# Couldn't find version of Python3 even though its installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

[image: Image of the error]

when installing module on NPM i get this error and i have python 3 installed and ENV path set.

tried to install a NPM module and expected to install

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'python'? Reset your path and reload cmd? Maybe ">=3.7" instead of "> =3.7"?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by try python? I just did the npm i install command.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. I meant try writing python instead of python3

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply deleting and instlaling python for microsoft store somehow fixed my problem lol,. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Cool, have fun with it :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Python and installing from Microsoft Store somehow fixed my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).